# How to avoid having pixelly textures?

Tags: texturing

So the process of creation of this mesh was as follows:

1. Quads (Edit Mode) > (applied) Subsurf mod
2. Sculpt mode > Dyntopo for details
3. Decimate mod

Not sure if this was supposed to look this way, it is not as bad, when rendered though.
Even though the mesh does not look as bad, I am aware that my workflow is not as 'correct' as it  should be I guess...

Wait, it IS pretty bad when rendered ... the bumb map really emphasized the pixeliness here...

Maybe for the future... how may I avoid such results (in having such pixelated textures), should I follow a different process/workflow? Or is it somehow System/Settings related? I tried tuning a bit with the Mipmaps and Anisotropic settings, not much changed...

This is probably a more broader question, but hey, I would appreciate any pointers or tips...

Thank you for your time
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JV1u.png)

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. What is the bottom left image? Add the image descriptions where it suggests to. Where is this "pixelinnes"? Do you mean at the dark brown patch on the right of the top image?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the descriptions, the editing in here is a bit confusing. On the top image, I painted the surface a bit (on the right side) (with yellow and brown colors). You can clearly see pixeliness... The Bottom left image is my mesh that I am trying to paint on.... I added a blue texture (bottom right) so you can see the 'pixeliness'....